# Open file for reading and writing with truncate

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I open a file for reading and writing that is also truncated to 0?

I've tried:

```
f = open(PATH, 'w+')
```

I'm unable to read from the file (`f.read()` returns an empty string), however.

Also:

```
f = os.fdopen(os.open(PATH, os.O_RDWR | os.O_TRUNC), 'r+')
```

Same behavious as the previous code.

Comment: Zed shows how to do this in his free ebook:  http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html

Comment: @the happy mamba: after `truncate(0)`, `write()` inserts some weird characters before writing the actual content

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to store the data then truncate use `r+`:

```
with open(PATH,"r+") as f:
    line = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: @someguy, no worries, you could use os.open but it is pretty straight forward to just seek and truncate

Comment: can you tell me how out of curiosity. As you can see from my question, I did try, but it didn't work.

Comment: @someguy, in your code you would still have to follow the same logic whether it be direct os.read or f.read.. etc.., if you did not seek back to the start before truncating and the data you wrote was less than what was there before then the file would get padded with null bytes.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a table of modes:

```
mode-string  | truncate? | create? | what's allowed
-------------+-----------+---------+----------------
     r       |    no     |  no     |  reading (only)
     w       |    yes    |  yes    |  writing (only)
     a       |    no     |  yes    |  writing (only), auto-appends
     r+      |    no     |  no     |  read and write
     w+      |    yes    |  yes    |  read and write
     a+      |    no     |  yes    |  read and (auto-appending) write
```

Note that there's a missing mode ("read and non-auto-append write, that will not truncate but will create").  If you want that one you must use the `os` functions.

(With all of these, add `b` to the end of the mode sequence to operate on bytes.  The behavior without `b` depends on Python2 vs Python3 and also the `universal_newlines` option.)

In addition to all of this, switching from "read mode" to "write mode", or vice versa, on any file opened with the `+` update-mode, requires a seek operation in most cases.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458114/1256452) for more.

---

Edit: here are the various `os` operations for opening files as defined for Unix-like systems:

```
os.open(path, flags, mode)
```

The `path` argument is pretty obvious, and the `mode` argument is used only if the file is going to be created (hence may be omitted if you leave out the `os.O_CREAT` flag).  If you do supply `mode`, the most common value is `0666` which corresponds to `rw-rw-rw-`.  The user's "umask" (see `os.umask`) will take away the unwanted permissions, e.g., a umask of `002` takes away the final write bit, resuling in `rw-rw-r--`, while `077` takes away all but the initial `rw-`.  The two other common modes are `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx` for executable files) and `0600` (`rw-------` for user-private files, such as temporary files when working with the user's email).

The `flags` value should include exactly one of `os.O_RDONLY`, `os.O_WRONLY`, or `os.O_RDWR`: open for reading (only), writing (only), or both.

To these, you can add<sup>1</sup> `os.O_CREAT`, meaning "create file if it does not exist"; `os.O_TRUNC`, meaning "truncate file to zero bytes in length immediately"; and/or `os.O_APPEND`, meaning "all os-level write operations implicitly seek to the current end-of-file just before writing".  There may (depending on OS flavor) be more flags such as `O_EXCL`, `O_NDELAY`, `O_NOFOLLOW` and more.  (The one that is perhaps most commonly useful and dependable is `O_EXCL`, which means "fail if this would open an existing file" and hence is only really useful when combined with `O_CREAT`.  Using the two together, you can make a new file that you can guarantee no other cooperating process in the system is also using.  The `O_NOFOLLOW` flag, if it exists, is also useful in some security contexts, to avoid symlink traps.)

In all cases, given whatever read/write settings you supply at the `os` level—i.e., `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`—if you then wrap the file descriptor into a Python stream with `os.fdopen`, you cannot gain additional powers that you did not grant yourself at `open` time.  You can only subtract some away, i.e., you can open with `O_RDWR` but then `fdopen` the stream as either read- or write-only.  In addition, when using `fdopen` with update mode, the annoying restriction of requiring seek or flush operations between different I/O directions remains in place.

Note that the `a` (append) mode at the `fdopen` level, if it's obeyed at all, is "less powerful" than the `O_APPEND` mode (or using `a` mode with `open` or `io.open`, all of which result in setting the underlying `O_APPEND` mode).  This mostly has to do with cooperating processes that share a file: if two or more such processes have files opened with `O_APPEND`, as long as their writes are "small enough" (the details vary again with OSes), their writes will not intermingle.  If the files are merely opened as `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`, two cooperating processes can call the underlying seek function and then the underlying write function, but if the two are racing each other, one may overwrite the other's data.

(Some flags, including `O_APPEND`, can be switched off and on using `fcntl` (from `import fcntl`) with the `F_SETFL` argument.  This was a relatively late addition to Python2.)

---

<sup>1</sup>"Add" here can mean literal addition, but using bitwise or `|` operations is more conventional.  That is, `os.open(os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT | os.O_TRUNC, 0666)`, not `os.open(os.O_RDWR + os.O_CREAT + os.O_TRUNC, 0666)`.

Comment: I'm aware of the `os` functions -- the 'what' -- but I need the 'how'. Your answer isn't really helpful otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean "how"?  The above *is* how, unless you are asking about the `os` functions...   Aha, per Padraic Cunningham's question, you meant "how to truncate at some point given that you've recently done some read or write operation".  I did not get that out of your question.

Comment: I'll fill in the `os` level functions for Linux/Unix-like systems.  It's still not at all clear to me what you're looking for though: each time I think I know what you're asking about, you say that's not what you're asking about.

Comment: One of the best answers in this space. Thanks for showing the table above.