# why does Python read(3) seek to end of file

Tags: python, io

I am trying to understand file IO in Python, with the different modes for open, and reading and writing to the same file object (just self learning).

I was surprised by the following code (which was just me exploring):

```py
with open('blah.txt', 'w') as f:

    # create a file with 13 characters
    f.write("hello, world!")


with open('blah.txt', 'r+') as f:

    for i in range(5):

        # write one character
        f.write(str(i))

        # then print current position and next 3 characters
        print(f"{f.tell()}: ", f"{f.read(3)}")


with open('blah.txt', 'r') as f:

    # look at how the file was modified
    print(f.read())
```

Which output:

```py
1:  ell
14:  
15:  
16:  
17:  
0ello, world!1234
```

As I expected, the first character was overwritten by `0`, then the next 3 characters read were `ell`, ***but*** I expected the `1` to be written over the `o` in `hello`, then the next 3 characters read to be `, w`.

I'm reading the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), but I don't see where it explains the behavior that I observed.

It appears that the first read, no matter what the size, seeks to the end of the file.

Can anyone provide a link to where it explains this in the docs?

I tried searching for a similar question on this site, but while there were many questions related to read, none that I found mentioned this behavior.

***UPDATE***

After more exploration, it is not the first `read` that seeks to the end of the file, but rather the second write that does. Again, I'm not sure why, which is why I'm hoping to find somewhere in the docs that explains this behavior.

Here's my change to the code above that shows that it's not the first read:

```py
with open('blah.txt', 'w') as f:

    # create a file with 13 characters
    f.write("hello, world!")


with open('blah.txt', 'r+') as f:

    for i in range(3):

        # write one character
        f.write(str(i))

        # then print current position and next 3 characters
        print(f"{f.tell()}: ", f"{f.read(3)}")
        print(f"{f.tell()}: ", f"{f.read(3)}")


with open('blah.txt', 'r') as f:

    # look at how the file was modified
    print(f.read())
```

Which output:

````py
1:  ell
4:  o, 
14:  
14:  
15:  
15:  
0ello, world!12```
````

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686536/flushing-fopened-files-opened-in-update-mode-between-read-and-write-operation

Comment: Although it is likely relevant, the linked question is one about C, not Python @ThierryLathuille - I can see how they would be related, but an answer to that effect would still be needed.

Comment: @Grismar This is exactly what I thought, and that's why I left this comment. Feel free to add an answer, I very probably won't! ;)

Comment: Thank you. I've been reading that question, and what it links to.  If I am understanding it correctly, this is related to buffering and I'm supposed to call flush between switch from write to read. Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe At least on Windows 7, `f.flush()` didn't help, but `f.seek(0, io.SEEK_CUR)` did.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457933/python-in-place-write-to-file-at-arbitrary-position?rq=3. This has more detail on the specification of the underlying C library (*"input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function"*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('HelloEmpty')

with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    print(f.read(5))
    print(f.write('World'))
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read(10))
```

You might expect this to print:

```
Hello
5
HelloWorld
```

Instead, it prints:

```
Hello
5
HelloEmpty
```

And the file contains `'HelloEmptyWorld'` after execution.

Even though this code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('HelloEmpty')

with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    print(f.read(5))
    print(f.read(5))
```

Works as expected and prints:

```
Hello
Empty
```

So, the `.read()` doesn't position the pointer at the end of the file, otherwise the second print statement should have caused an error or come up empty.

However, consider this example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(10000):
        f.write('HelloEmpty')

with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    print(f.read(5))
    print(f.write('World'))
```

If you execute this code, and then look at the file, you will find that at position 8193, the word 'World' has been written.

So, it appears that Python reads the text data in 8192 byte or character chunks, and although consecutive calls to `.read()` track the position in the read buffer, calls to `.write()` will use the actual file pointer, which has been moved 8k ahead (or to the end of the file, whichever comes first).

Whether it's characters or bytes, you can tell from this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf16') as f:
    for _ in range(10000):
        f.write('HelloEmpty')

with open('test.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf16') as f:
    print(f.read(5))
    print(f.write('World'))
```

Now, the character size in the file is 2 bytes, and the word 'world' gets written at position 4097 (in characters, but still after byte 8192), so the buffer size is in bytes.

(note that 8192 and 4096 are powers of two, in case those numbers seem arbitrary; also note that the first large file is exactly 100000 bytes in size, as expected, but the second one is 200002 bytes in size, which causes the world `'World'` to be offset a bit, due to the encoding chosen and the byte order mark)

Edit, a bit more information:

Consider this:

```
with open('test1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('x' * 100000)

with open('test1.txt', 'r+') as f:
    s1 = f.read(5)    # 5. read first 5 bytes, expected to be 'xxxxx'
    f.seek(0)         # 6. seek back to beginning of file
    f.write('y' * 5)  # 7. write 5 bytes of 'yyyyy'
    f.read(5)         # 8. then read another 5 bytes (discarded, but would be 'xxxxx')
    f.flush()         # 9. flush the buffer, if any
    f.seek(0)         # 10. seek the beginning of the file once more
    s2 = f.read(5)    # 11. read 5 characters, expected to be 'yyyyy', but in fact 'xxxxx' (Win 10, Python 3.11.6)

print(s1, s2)

# without line 8:
with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('x' * 100000)

with open('test2.txt', 'r+') as f:
    s1 = f.read(5)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write('y' * 5)
    # f.read(5)
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    s2 = f.read(5)

print(s1, s2)         # the expected result
```

Output:

```
xxxxx xxxxx
xxxxx yyyyy
```

This shows that performing a `.read()` after a `.write()`, before flushing the buffer, can cause very unexpected results. You'll find that `test2.txt` will have `yyyyy` written at the start, as expected, but `test1.txt` will have it written after the first read buffer.

I'm not sure if this shouldn't in fact be considered a bug in Python...

Comment: I didn't find a reference to this chunk size in the documentation on python.org - if anyone has a link to the actual documentation, please do post it. `_io` is compiled directly into the interpreter, so its implementation details are a bit hidden as well.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I hope it is documented somewhere.

Comment: Yes, your latest example shows the need to flush the buffers between switching directions (read/write), as mentioned in the answer linked to in the answer linked to by @Thierry Lathuille (i.e. follow two links) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1713819/6394617). I don't know if Python would consider it a bug, but apparently C doesn't.

Comment: I don't know if you want to include this in your answer, but I've learned from the docs that you can read/write without a buffer using [Raw I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#raw-i-o) by calling `open('blah.txt', 'rb+', buffering=0)`.  Of course, then you need to read and write bytes.  I cannot find a way to read without buffering in Text I/O, but there is a [write_through](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) parameter that allows unbuffered write.

Comment: I think that's perfect as a comment - it's not generally the way this problem should be solved, and too many ifs, buts and maybes don't make the answer better. But it's definitely worth noting here.